# How to add parameter at the end of the URL

Tags: c#, wcf

i created one wcf service in c#.and i successful publish it.now i want to pass parameter in the URL and wcf will return data in json format.but i am trying than i am not getting any answer.so can you help me how add parameter at the end of the URL.

***IwcfDataService.cs***

```
namespace RestWCFService
{

    [ServiceContract]
    public interface IWcfDataService
    {
        [OperationContract]
        [WebInvoke(Method = "GET",
         ResponseFormat = WebMessageFormat.Json,
         BodyStyle = WebMessageBodyStyle.Wrapped,
         UriTemplate = "Search?keyword={keyword}")]
        List<string> Search(string keyword);
    }

    [DataContract]
    public class Detail
    {

        [DataMember]
        public string InnerText { get; set; }

        [DataMember]
        public string URL { get; set; }

        [DataMember]
        public string Title { get; set; }


    } 
}
```

***WcfDataService.svc.cs***

```
namespace RestWCFService
{

    public class WcfDataService : IWcfDataService
    {

        public List<string> Search(string keyword)
        {
                 SqlConnection sql_Search;


                 sql_Search = new SqlConnection("Data Source=FPBLWD0310;Initial Catalog=Support;Integrated Security=True");
                 sql_Search.Open();
                 SqlCommand SelectCommand = new SqlCommand("SELECT KeyWords,URLName,Title FROM finalCrawler Where (KeyWords Like '%" + keyword + "%')", sql_Search);


                 SelectCommand.ExecuteNonQuery();
                 SqlDataAdapter SQLAd = new SqlDataAdapter(SelectCommand);
                 SqlDataReader read = SelectCommand.ExecuteReader();
                 Detail De = null;
                 List<string> ListDetail = new List<string>();
                 while (read.Read())
                 {
                      De = new Detail { 
                       InnerText = read["KeyWords"].ToString(),
                       URL = read["URLName"].ToString(),
                       Title  = read["Title"].ToString()
                    };
                      var javaScriptSerializer = new
     System.Web.Script.Serialization.JavaScriptSerializer();
                      string jsonString = javaScriptSerializer.Serialize(De);
                      ListDetail.Add(jsonString);
                 }

                 sql_Search.Close();  


           return ListDetail;

        }
```

***URL***
so can you tell me how i add parameter at the end of the URL so i get the result

```
 http://localhost:8434/WcfDataService.svc?singleWsdl
```

Comment: Side note - please use `SQLParameter`s on your `SQLCommand` - what you have written is vulnerable to SQL injection, meaning a malicious user could enter SQL script instead of a keyword - exposing your database to all kinds of attacks such as dropping tables etc. Google for more info.

Answer (score 1):

Simply use this to build your url parameters:

```
url += string.Format("&TabName={0}", HttpUtility.UrlEncode(tabName));
```

Comment: It is just an example, this is how I use this in my code. Replace by a name that makes sense to you.